# Retina button not working in Apple Mail (iOS6 and iOS7)

Tags: email, ios7, media-queries, retina-display

I was having an issue in Apple Mail where the retina image wouldn't resize. My code was:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .retina { 
        background: url(image@2x.png) no-repeat center 24px !important; 
        background-size: 40px 28px;
    }
}
```

I've updated the retina media queries and added !important declarations to background-size and the button displays fine. However, now the link on the button does not work in Apple Mail running iOS7.

```
@media 
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), 
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) {
    .retina { 
        background: url(image@2x.png) no-repeat center 24px !important; 
        background-size: 40px 28px !important;
    }
}
```

The button works as a link in all other mail clients, including Mail.app running OSX 10.8.5 when the window is made smaller to show the "mobile" version. Any solution to how I can get the button working as a link?